# Surface Material effects more than the selected object

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm applying a glass material to the surface of an object in my scene. In this case the 'V_'

Why does the surface effect also happen to the backdrop?

I only want the effect on the 'V_'

Thank you[image]

Comment: hello, do they have the same material?

Comment: Hello, yes. The glass effect I want applied just the V_ is also effecting the backdrop which I don't want to happen.

Comment: So you just need to assign another material to your plane